# Rotating proxies that require authentication using selenium undetected chrome driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver, proxies

Hello everyone  I want to scrape [this](https://www.hermes.com/fr/fr/) website but I need to rotate proxies since I always get blocked. [Please note that I am a beginner ]

Also I need to use `Selenium webdriver` (I tried to use only the requests library with BeautifulSoup but I get the following error 'Please enable JS and disable adblocker' , I also heard that I could use the request-html library [a more recent library , that enables javascript] I tried but with no success... ).

Moreover I use the undetected-chromedriver from this [library](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) (I read on forums that this library allowed a better headers optimization [am I right ? ])

So my problematic is the following : how can I rotate proxies using paid proxies  (that need a username and a password , I bought datacenter proxies from [SmartProxy](https://smartproxy.com) ) with Selenium undetected chrome driver ?

Here is what I tried :

My proxy list ( paid proxies ) look something like this (they are in a text file called : smartproxies.txt )

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dc.smartproxy.com:10001
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dc.smartproxy.com:10002
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dc.smartproxy.com:10003
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dc.smartproxy.com:10004
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@dc.smartproxy.com:10005
```

Then I used a for loop to iterate through all my proxies and go to this page : https://api.ipify.org/ a page that allows you to know your ip (just to see if i have correctly rotated proxies ) here is my script :

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


def sele(url, using_proxies=True):
    with open('smartproxies.txt', 'r') as f:
        proxies_list = f.read().splitlines()
    for proxy in proxies_list:
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(3)
        driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sele(url="https://api.ipify.org/")
```

However when the script runs , the page that open at each iteration of the loop shows me the same IP address ! I don't see my error

Also , is it really necessary to use the undetected chromedriver for that or would a regular chrome driver work ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should read the terms of the site you're trying to scrape: _"you are prohibited from reproducing in whole or in part, by any means whatsoever, distributing, publishing, transmitting, modifying or selling all or part of the content of the Hermes.com site, or creating derivative works from it."_ (Translation by Bing) The site owners don't want you doing this, are defending against it, and I suspect may take legal action if they catch you.